# Temporary storage of sensitive information in Javascript

Tags: encryption, data-leakage, sensitive-data-exposure

I am working at a university where we are creating a Website that allows students to apply for scholarships. Rather than print the application form, sign it then scan it then return it back, the website allows student to digitally sign the application forms (aka e-signature).

Since there are multiple documents which the users can also sign, we temporarily store the base64 format of the signature image in javascript (in a javascript variable) then reference it later on to sign the other documents sent to him/her that also require signing. It javascript variable will be deleted when user goes back to the home page of the site.

Is this secure? I mean the digital signature in base64 format is considered a PII (Personally Identifiable Information) right? In this case, would this require encryption when temporarily stored?

Comment: It's as safe as anything else on the page, yes. You don't store the information, so why would it need encrypted? Even if it was stored, it's not stored by you, so you don't have to protect it; the user assumes responsibility for their equipment.

Comment: got it @dandavis. One follow up question: so when does it fall into the category of "being stored at rest" and therefore needs to encrypted?

Comment: storage vs memory: if you have the info, and still have it when power goes out, that's at rest.